# Tomcat write permission apache server user uploads

Tags: java, tomcat

When a user uploads an image, the file is created in "/var/www/example.com/uploads" by the tomcat webapp so that apache can serve the image. However, the tomcat group/user creates the file so it is not accessible through example.com/uploads/image.jpg unless I manually change the read permissions, then the file is no longer forbidden. But, every file is created without read permissions. I am not fluent with ubuntu and I do not know if I need to change something within the java servlet or to the folder/group/user. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
-rw-r----- 1 tomcat tomcat 120264 Jul 14 19:26 second-image.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat 172853 Jul 14 19:05 image.png
```

Edit:
The file is submitted as multipart config form data. After checking the types, size, etc., it is written to the system simply as:

```
Path imageDir = Path.of("/var/www/example.com/uploads");
Path imageFile = Files.createFile(imageDir.resolve(fileName).toAbsolutePath());
part.write(imageFile.toString());
```

Comment: Also, checking the permissions of the directory. Unless the directory has execute, the file is not loaded in the webpage.

Comment: Please post a minimal example of the application code that writes these files. It can be done in a number of ways, using provided libraries or 3rd-party code, all of which affect potential answers.

Comment: Sure, just updated the post.

Comment: Also, this all worked on my PC before I moved it to the server. Of course, it is Windows and the file permissions are different, which I learned the hard way when I moved it to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application code is already calling a method that is able to set permissions, but isn't providing a parameter to do so. You can read [this tutorial on File Attributes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html#posix) to see an example of setting file permissions. I'm guessing you'd want to create the permissions from a string, since you're already working with the format:

```
Set<PosixFilePermission> perms =
PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rw-------");
FileAttribute<Set<PosixFilePermission>> attr = PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttribute(perms);
Files.createFile(file, attr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I modified the code as you suggested but the file attributes did not actually change. I changed the string to "rw-r--r--" but the file still uploaded as "rw-r-----". Any thoughts on why this may not have worked?

Comment: Perhaps the tomcat user doesn't have permission for the operation, or something else about the environment interferes.

Comment: I figured it out. It turns out that part.write() changes the already set permissions back. I had to use Files.setPosixFilePermissions(imageFile, perms) after writing the file with part.write(). Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I'm glad to hear you got it working! Good job investigating.